# Terminal: remains of an old chain and bad positioning of the cursor

Tags: console

This is my PS1 variable for the terminal:

```
PS1='\n\e[1;36m┌[\w]\n┤\n└\]\e[1;00m[\u@\h][\$]'[\$?]'\]\e[0m\] '
```

When I type a long string like "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(cursor)" and press the up arrow to look for and "old typed string", this occurs to me:

```
xxxxxxxxxold typed string(cursor)
```

The terminal delete only part por the "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" typed string. how could i correct this behavior? Thanks